# Is X,that relates to each ionization experiment outcome the ionization time or $\infty$ if the atom wasn't ionized,a valid continuous random variable?

Tags: probability

Essentially, I want to show that given a probability ionization rate, $W_i(t)\equiv W_i(E(t))$, where E is the strength of a laser electric field, the probability of the ionization of an atom by the laser pulse is given by $Pr=1-exp\{-\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} W_i(t)dt \}$.

To do this I denote by $X$ a continuous random variable which relates to each ionization experiment the time the atom was ionized with respect to the time $t=0$    of the arrival of the laser pulse peak to the atom location, or $\infty$ if the atom was not ionized. However, doing this I get something unreasonable by the derivation, so I thought maybe the definition of $X$ as a continuous random variable is incorrect.

Here is the derivation:

We have:
$$W_i(t)dt=Pr\left\{t\leq X \leq t+dt \; \mid \; t \leq X \right\}$$
Using the definition of conditional probability we get:
$$W_i(t)dt=\frac{Pr\left\{t\leq X \leq t+dt \;\;\;and\;\;\; t \leq X \right\}}{Pr\{t \leq X \}}=\frac{Pr\left\{t\leq X \leq t+dt \right\}}{1-Pr\{X < t \}}$$

Now, using the definitions of the ’probability density function’ of a
random variable $X$, $f_X$, and that of the ’cumulative distribution function’, $F_X$, of the random variable $X$, we get:
$$W_i(t)dt=\frac{\int_t^{t+dt}{f_X\left(t'\right)dt' } }{1-F_X\left(t\right)}$$
For a small enough time interval $dt$ the above can be approximated to:
$$W_i(t)dt\approx\frac{f_X\left(t\right)}{1-F_X\left(t\right)} dt$$
Using the relation between the ’probability density function’ and the ’cumulative distribution function’ we get:
$$W_i(t)=\frac{\frac{d}{dt} F_X\left(t\right)}{1-F_X\left(t\right)}$$
Integrating both sides of the equation gives:
$$ln\left(1-F_X(t)\right)=-\int_{-\infty}^t\textrm{W}_i(t)dt + C_0$$
or:
$$1-F_X(t)=exp\left\{C_0\right\}\cdot exp\left\{-\int_{-\infty}^t\textrm{W}_i(t)dt\right\}$$
Taking the limit $t\rightarrow -\infty$ of both sides of the above equation, and using the property of the ’cumulative distribution function’: $\,\lim\limits_{b\rightarrow -\infty}F_X(b)=0\;$,  shows that $C_0=0$, and thus:
$$F_X(t)=1-exp\left\{-\int_{-\infty}^t\textrm{W}_i(t)dt\right\}
$$
The total probability of ionization of an atom by the laser pulse, $Pr_{pulse}$, is given by:
$$Pr_{pulse}\equiv \lim\limits_{t \to \infty} Pr\left(X \leq t\right) \equiv \lim\limits_{t \to \infty} F_X(t)=1-exp\{-\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} W_i(t)dt \}
$$
However, a known property of the ’cumulative distribution function’ is: $\,\lim\limits_{b\rightarrow \infty}F_X(b)=1\,$, which contradicts the above result.

Where is the error?? Is it in the above definition of $X$ as a continuous random variable? How can I correct this derivation ??

Please help me!!